# Mark cells that contain words from a FILTER list

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a list of words in a basket which I want to pre-select through a FILTER list and color code the words in the basket which appear in the FILTER sheet. The challenge is, that the words in the basket have not the same word, but rather contain it. [Here an example >](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HvjHZOwAuRkSs9tE1p4_ZmsUDr8t6DFGedwwS1eKvNc/edit#gid=0)

FILTER:

```
+--------+
| Apple  |
+--------+
| Banana |
+--------+
```

Basket:

```
+--------------+---+
| Apple//Cake  | x |
+--------------+---+
| Water        |   |
+--------------+---+
| Coke bottle  |   |
+--------------+---+
| Banana split | x |
+--------------+---+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=(A2<>"")*(INDEX(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A2), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, LOWER(INDIRECT("FILTER!A:A"))))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you think you could explain what's happening in your formula, just so I understand it?

Comment: sure, if A2 is not empty AND (the multiplication) regex detects partial match between lowercased A column and lowercased list from your A column in your Filter sheet. if you want more strict matching you can remove both LOWER which will cause that formula will be case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula as a rule in `Conditional formatting`

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2,""&JOIN("|",INDIRECT("'FILTER'!A1:A3"))&"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you think you could explain me what that part is doing in your code? `"&JOIN("|",INDIRECT("'FILTER'!A1:A3"))&"")`. I understand the INDIRECT, but not what's happening before and after.

Comment: If we had `REGEXMATCH` for just `Banana`, it would return `TRUE` for just the cells containing `Banana`. We would then need 3 rules, 1 for each of our filter. We use `JOIN` and `|` as the delimiter to join all 3 words to just one regular expression `Banana|Apple|Water`. The delimiter `|` in the expression functions as `OR`. Please read about the functions used eg. [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292). If in more need, please ask again.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. While I like the shorter version of your formula I think `FILTER!A:A` doesn't work. Since my filter list might extend, it would be useful to not think about that. Is it possible to adjust your formula to that? Otherwise I would go with @player0 where that part seems to be solved aready.

Comment: *"I think `FILTER!A:A` doesn't work"*. Correct. *"Since my filter list might extend,.... I would go with @player0 where that part seems to be solved already"*. No problem. It is a better approach in your case.